# не хочет работать autoheight в swiper

Tags: jquery, swiper

стоит задача поставить autoheight, но не могу понять то ли из за верстки, то ли еще из за чего, свайпер вообще не хочет менять высоту, берет высоту первого и не меняется дальше. Думал что дело в стилях, но увы ничего не добился.

Настройки и вот сама [страница](https://icpcentre.org/courses/complete-coaching-course/)

```
    {new Swiper(".capabilities-reviews__slider",
{slidesPerView:1,autoHeight:!1,loop:!1,pagination:
{el:".capabilities-reviews__dots",bulletClass:"slider__dots-item",bulletActiveClass:"slider__dots-item--active capabilities-reviews__dots-item--active",renderBullet:function(e,t)
{return'<li class="'.concat(t,'"><div class="slider__dot slider__dot--blue capabilities-reviews__dot"></div></li>')},clickable:!0}})}
```

Comment: это что `autoHeight:!1` ?

Comment: ну это типо true

Comment: 1 = true, !1 = false - знак восклицания делает отрицание